# Automatic checkout from TortoiseSVN

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, svnkit

I'm trying to do an automatic checkout from Subversion. But the problem is, it is not working for me. I did this:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe"  /command:checkout  /path:"C:\Program\Client" /url:"http://subversion/svn/Client/ClientsVersion/trunk/"
```

But then I need to click on 'OK' and type my username + password. But I want to execute a command and then everything is done.

I'm executing the command in Java with Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start CODE");, So if there is another solution in Java that also will work for me!

This is now my code and working for svnKit version 1.3.7

```
File dstPath = new File("c:/svnkit");
SVNURL url;
url = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("http://subversion/svn/directory/project/trunk/");
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager("USERNAME", "PASS" );
SVNUpdateClient uc = new SVNUpdateClient(authManager , SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true)); 
uc.doCheckout(url, dstPath, SVNRevision.UNDEFINED, SVNRevision.HEAD,  SVNDepth.INFINITY, true);
```

Comment: To state the obvious, you need to pass username and password. In svn:checkout, the flags would be --username and --password. Can you post the code which calls the above line?

Comment: I will execute the Command line in Java with: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start CODE"); if there is a solution in Java that will also work for me ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the command line client (svn.exe instead of TortoiseSVN) for checking out via java. Furthermore if you really need a solution for Java only you can take a look into svnkit.com for native Java library which means you don't need calling a command line client anymore. Currently the svnkit library doesn't support 1.7 (but via an alpha version).

Comment: There is no svn.exe on my PC? I installed TurtoiseSVN. 

Is it possible to use the svnkit and checkout some data in another directory then the project?

Comment: Ok. Than the best way to handle that is to use svnkit.com instead. SVNKit gives you all freedom to work like if you had installed the svn.exe command line client etc.

Comment: I have set some code in my question post, have you any idea what is wrong with it?

Comment: It was a bug in the newest version of svnKit, So I now use the version before and now it is working! Thanks alot!

Comment: @Gynnad - in case of TSVN **1.7** you can select at install-time "Install command-line tools" also